# What makes W1 (C80U) a tool steel compared to 1080 (C80) steel?

Tags: materials

I don't know why W1 is considered tool steel, if it's a carbon steel that has the same amount of carbon as 1080 steel. ISO calls it C80U, and 1080 C80, so they are very similar. So what makes C80U so special?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it is more than a name ,or call it 110 Class tool steel in US. I always wondered about the P 1 to 5 "tool steels" because they are ordinary low carbon low alloy steels.  One specific difference can be price; Something priced as a "tool steel" may have a different price from "AISI 1080 hot rolled ". I have not seen this in tool steels but I have seen it in pipe. When pricing 13 Cr pipe, two mills had substantially different prices ( same pipe). We found one mill called it alloy steel . The other mill called it "stainless steel" and added a much higher overhead to the basic cost of the pipe.